# How to sort the files according to the time stamp in unix?

Tags: unix, unix-timestamp

How to sort the files according to the time stamp in unix?
I need to sort the files and also based on time they created.

Comment: Which timestamp? Also, there is no creation timestamp on most *nix filesystems.

Comment: time stamp with which the file is created.

Comment: try `ls -Ct | awk '{print $1}'`

Answer (score 176, accepted):

File modification:

```
ls -t
```

Inode change:

```
ls -tc
```

File access:

```
ls -tu
```

"Newest" one at the bottom:

```
ls -tr
```

None of this is a creation time. Most Unix filesystems don't support creation timestamps.

Comment: Actually, many *nix filesystems do support creation timestamp… it's just not cross-platform. On FreeBSD and OS X, it's generally only available on native BSD filesystems (including HFS+ on OS X); it's called "file creation time", and `ls -U` sorts by it. On Linux, it's available on most filesystems that support it (even including NTFS), but it's called "birth time", and you have to sort manually.

Answer (score 20):

Use -t on ls.  e.g:.

```
ls -tr
```

or

```
ls -ltr
```