# Check on which pages an image is used?

Tags: image, http-status-code-404

Is there a certain way to check which pages on a website use a specific image?

Say I have some image which I don't use on a page anymore, so I'd like to delete it from my server. But I'm not entirely sure if it's being used on other pages, is there a way to check if it's still being shown on other pages?

Comment: Are your pictures hardcoded in the pages or do they come out of a database?

Comment: The images are hardcoded in the pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can hook your website to google webmaster tools and wait a little bit after a while 404 errors will appear there. This way you can track unused resources and dead ends.

This includes images.

There is a better way if you have direct access to the web server.

Visit every page in your website or let google crawl it. 
You can later sort the files by date modified and ones which are not modified lately are not used.

You have to make sure you get the images from the pages so I would use a historyless cahceless session.

[How to sort the files according to the time stamp in unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023726/how-to-sort-the-files-according-to-the-time-stamp-in-unix)

Comment: I might give this a try. 
I haven't deleted the images yet, with this method there will be a 'gap' of time where there might be pages that have images that won't show. 

I guess that is unavoidable?

Comment: @Gerb updated my answer with a better solution. This also have no latency